# How do I change the working directory for debugging in VS Code + CMakeTools

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I have a VS Code project based on a CMakeLists.txt file, and using the CMakeTools extension I can successfully build the target executable.

However, I need to run the executable in a different directory to the build directory.  I cannot find a setting to either:

1. The built executable is placed in a different directory to the build directory and then run from there
2. The build executable is run from a different working directory

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the output directory for the executable using the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property. When debugging, the executable is run in that directory. For example:

```
set_target_properties(my_target
    PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
```

If you only want to change the current working directory (cwd), you can create your custom `.vscode/launch.json`. The content may depend on your OS and compiler:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run CMake Target",
            "type": "cppvsdbg", // use cppdbg on linux
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bin"
        }
    ]
}
```